# I can't fetch data from database from inside a decorator in Flask app

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-python

I can access the database outside a decorator, but when I'm inside the decorator, the sql query doesn't return anything. It returns a NoneType, it says.

This is the html that is being sent to the app.

```
<form action="/22" method="post" class="reveal-content">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Send</button>
```

This is my flask app decorator that handles the request.
(I pass a parameter (22) into the decorator because i want to filter it in the query. Here I just put a simple SELECT * query for simplicity)

```
@app.route('/<int:store_id>', methods=["POST"])
def stores(store_id):
    select_query = ("SELECT * FROM stores")
    
    mycursor.execute(select_query)
    result = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        print(row)
    return render_template("work.html")
```

This is the code that works fine and returns rows from the database.

```
sql_select_formula = ("SELECT * FROM stores")
mycursor.execute(sql_select_formula)
result = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in result:
    print(x)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: as side note, why you declare `select_query` and `sql_select_formula` as tuples ? it should be of type string.

Comment: I was using tuples because I needed it to do more specific queries.
But I changed the tuple here to a string and it still doesnt return any row.

Its really weird, because the query returns correctly when used outside the decorator. :(